# The Existence of $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ with $\sup_{x} |\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|<M$where $M$ is independent of $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

I hope to know the existence of the function $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ such that 
$$\sup_{x} |\partial^{\alpha}f(x)|<M$$
where $M$ is independent of $\alpha$.

If that function exists, I hope to know the existence of the function $\phi \in C_{c}^{\infty}$ such that $\sup_{x} |\partial^{\alpha}\phi(x)|<M$, $\phi(x)=1$ if $x$ is in $[-1,1]$, and $\phi(x)=0$ if $x$ is in $(-\infty,-2] \cup [2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having uniformly bounded derivatives implies that the function is analytic.  This can be seen pretty easily by seeing that the remainder term in the Taylor approximation converges to $0$.  Since there are no non-zero compactly supported analytic functions, the function you are seeking does not exist.